# Variables in C#

Tags: c#, variables

I've been searching for answers to solve this tiny bit of code, but without luck. I figure I have to declare the variable for "item" outside the method, but I can't seem to find a way to do so.

[beginner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbIy1.png)

```
namespace Items
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool myBool = true;

            while (myBool)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
                Console.WriteLine("[1] - add item");
                Console.WriteLine("[2] - see content");
                Console.WriteLine("[3] - erase content");
                Console.WriteLine("[4] - close");

                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("add item");

                        var item = (Console.ReadLine());

                        Console.WriteLine("you just added: " + item);
                        break;

                    case 2: 
                        Console.WriteLine("items added: " + items);
                        break;

                    case 3:  
                        myBool = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not put it along `myBool` ? Leavit empty and fill it in the loop. Note that the really are not 'methods' in the code you show.

Comment: There's only one method in your question, so it's not 100% clear what you mean by "different methods". That said, most likely you are having trouble with variable scoping. See duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not quite clear what you're asking here - questions should typically include what you expect the code to do, and what it actually does. That said, I think I can see what you're going for. I've updated the code, and added some comments to describe the changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; // This namespace contains the 'List<>' class

namespace Items
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // I've moved this outside of the loop - I assume users would want the help message
            // displayed on startup, not every single time they do something.
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] - add item");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] - see content");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] - erase content");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] - close");

            // The list of items is created here, outside of the main loop.
            var items = new List<string>();

            // You don't need to declare a variable 'myBool' here
            // We can just loop until the user exits the whole program
            while (true)
            {
                int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (input)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("add item");
                        var newItem = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("you just added: " + newItem);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Console.WriteLine("items added:");
                        foreach (var item in items)
                            Console.WriteLine(item);

                    break;

                    case 3:
                        items.Clear();
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend following some tutorials first, so you get an idea of variable scope - how long a variable lives for and where it can be accessed from.

Comment: Thank you so much for the respons! Sorry for not being clear with my intentions for the code, I don't need a list of items, I just want to be able to call for the items written down by the user in Case 1 into Case 2.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to do here. On line 33, do you want to show all the items, or just the previous item to be added?

The error you're getting is that the variable "items" doesn't exist. If you just want to show the previous item to be added, then you can replace the word "items" with "item", and move the line where you declare "item" to outside the switch statement, to look like this:

```html
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        bool myBool = true;
        
        var item;

        while (myBool)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
            Console.WriteLine("[1] - add item");
            Console.WriteLine("[2] - see content");
            Console.WriteLine("[3] - erase content");
            Console.WriteLine("[4] - close");

            int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        
        switch (input)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("add item");

                    item = (Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("you just added: " + item);
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    Console.WriteLine("items added: " + item);

                    break;

                 case 3:  
                    myBool = false;

                    break;
            }
```

Now, we're declaring the variable item in the Main method rather than in the switch statement. Before, when you were declaring it in the switch statement, it was being reset every time you restarted the loop. Now, when the user changes it by inputting a value, it will be saved when you go back to the start of the loop, and so if the user inputs "2", they will be shown the last item they inputted.

If you want the user to be shown every item they have inputted, you'll need to use an array or collection.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! Sorry for not being clear about my intentions for my code. I only want to use the input in case 1 into case 2. When I run this code, with the "var item" outside the switch-statement, I get an error: "Implicitly-typed variables must be initialized".

Comment: Change the declaration from `var input;` to either `var input = string.Empty;` or `string input = null;`